# has_and_belongs_to_many UndefinedTable: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, `Clinician` and `Patient`.  A `clinician` `has_many: patients` and a `patient` `belongs_to :clinician`.  A join table, `shared_patients` is meant to store additional associations between `patients` and `clinicians` as a `patient` can be shared by many other `clinicians` besides the one it `belongs_to`.  This is done using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

See models:

```
class Clinician < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :patients
 has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_patients, join_table: 'shared_patients', class_name: 'Patient'
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :clinician
 has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_clinicians, join_table: 'shared_patients', class_name: 'Clinician'
end
```

This is how my tables are set out in the db schema:

```
create_table "clinicians", force: true do |t|
  t.string  "first_name"
  t.string  "last_name"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

create_table "patients", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "clinician_id"
  t.string  "first_name"
  t.string  "last_name"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

create_table "shared_patients", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "clinician_id"
  t.integer "patient_id"
end
```

Using these I would like to show the list of `clinicians` that a `patient` is shared with.

Right now I am getting an error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "shared_patients" does not exist
>   LINE 1: INSERT INTO "shared_patients" ("clinician_id", "id", "patien...

If I try and create a relationship in console:

> @shared = SharedPatient.new("id"=>1, "clinician_id"=>2526, "patient_id"=>1307)
>   => #1, "clinician_id"=>2526, "patient_id"=>1307}>
>
> @shared.save

Any advice on solving this error or on structuring the models to get the associations I want would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` then you cannot have a class for the join table, ie. you can't have `SharedPatient` and you can't try using it as you've done.